# AspectJ on Confluence

Tags: java, aspectj, confluence

Hello we are running Confluence 5.5.1 and we would like to start working with aop programming. The plugin that utilises aop throws an

`BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/reflect/AjTypeSystem`

because aspectj is not part of the confluence.

I tried to add the aspectjrt 1.6.11 in the $CONFLUENCE_HOME/confluence/WEB-INF/lib without success. Then extracted the jar atlassian-plugins-osgi-3.0.15.jar in order to include the aspectjrt in the osgi-framework-bundles.zip but still no success.

Is there some other workaround I can do in order to be able to work with aspectj?

The plugin breaks when insert `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to an .xml in the META-INF folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread in Answers, it seems to be the same issue

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/5352

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've seen that question in the atlassian. It is suggested to add the aspectjrt-XXX.jar in the atlassian-plugins-osgi-3.0.15.jar which turns out not to work, not for me at least (without changing any code).